# The digit at the hundred's place of $33^{33}$

Tags: binomial-theorem, number-systems

I would want to know how to start with the question. And if you get hung up somewhere there's the answer it's $5$.
Any help is appreciated thanks,

My approach was to look at the factors to somehow crack the nut. But still in vain. Any help or tip or approach is alright as I didn't get a clue but for that. Yeah and also do suggest a category as well if number systems isn't appropriate.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange. To get the answers at your level, to learn most and to prevent people form giving hints you already know, you should include your attempt. You can edit your post to add it.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I don't know even to start. So any hint will help I'll edit it in my answer though

Comment: Start experimenting, what happens when you square 33, and then cube it, etc?  Sometimes you have to play around to find a pattern.

Comment: 33 1089 35937 that's how it comes out to be . No pattern I guess.

Comment: Guys should I add a tag of binomial theorem

Comment: Have you learned about modular arithmetics, that is, $a \equiv b \pmod m$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Hundred's place probably means the third digit, i.e., $3$ in $654321$.

Comment: Due to $33\approx 10^{3/2}$ $33^{33}\approx 10^{50}$

Comment: Yes its the third digit don't worry

Comment: And no it's not modular I haven't got that in my syllabus

Comment: Note that repeated squaring is efficient here, because it gets easily to $33^{32}$

Comment: No need for the full machinery of modular arithmetic - just notice that the last three digits of a product don't depend on the thousands digits of the numbers you are multiplying. Or in different language $(1000x+a)(1000y+b)=1000000xy+1000ay+1000bx+ab$ so as you multiply up you only need to keep track of the last three digits at each stage.

Comment: Mr. Bennet there has to be some other way as in my test (where I found this) there is no calculator and the average time is 3 minutes

Comment: Let $[n]$ be the right-most three digits of $n$. We have $[33^2]=089,[33^4]=921,[33^8]=241,[33^{16}]=081,[33^{32}]=561,[33^{33}]=\color{red}{5}13$.

Comment: On the binomial theorem better to use $(30+3)^{33}$ or $3^{33}(10+1)^{33}$ which are essentially the same and can be done very easily if you know $3^{33}$. Picking out $30$ or $10$ makes most of the terms drop out as multiples of $1000$. $3^8=6561$ is easy to reach, and $(500\pm x)^2\equiv x^2 \bmod 1000$

Comment: Yes so we have found three possible ways of doing the same thing. From no idea to do it by myself thanks guys really helped for the whole type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes, to see how quickly it can be done. Jack's extraction of a factor $8$ from the modulus is helpful.

Let's work with "the last three digits", using $\equiv$ when the thousands are dropped, but allow negative numbers if that simplifies things.

$$33^2=1089$$

$$33^4\equiv89^2=(90-1)^2=7921\equiv-79$$

$$33^8\equiv (-79)^2=(80-1)^2=6241\equiv 241$$

It is here that being able to work mod $125$ would simplify things markedly, because you would have $33^{16}\equiv (-9)^2=81$ and $33^{32}\equiv 81^2=6561\equiv 61$ (modulo $125$) but I didn't spot that. So I'd do $$33^{16}\equiv 241^2=(250-9)^2=62500-4500+81\equiv81$$ which comes to the same thing and $$33^{32}\equiv 81^2=6561\equiv 561$$

$$561\times 33 =11 \times 1683 = \dots 513$$

There isn't a lot of thinking time, but done confidently and quickly, there is nothing there to take lots of time - and it helps to know two digit squares.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBennet for the very simple answer. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

We just have to compute $33^{33}\pmod{1000}$, hence $33^{33}\pmod{8}$ and $33^{33}\pmod{125}$.

$$33^{33}\equiv 33^{1}\equiv 1\pmod{8}\tag{1}$$
is easy to find, and 
$$ 33^{33}= 33\cdot 33^{32} = 33\cdot ((((33^2)^2)^2)^2)^2\tag{2}$$
gives:
$$ 33^{33} \equiv 13\pmod{125}, \tag{3}$$
hence, by the Chinese theorem:
$$ 33^{33}\equiv \color{red}{5}13\pmod{1000}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: The answer seems to be okay but the problem is I don't know modular arithmetic and its not even in my book by the way I'm 17.

Comment: @IlayaRajaS: modular arithmetic or not, the key is just to use $(2)$ as also suggested by mathlove in the comments.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How do you get (3) out of (2)?

Comment: Ok now I got it due to my low reputation I can't upvote the answer. It's now that I realize that mod() is nothing but remainder that comes by division.

Comment: So this can also be done using binomial theorem then like (33)^33=(32+1)^33 and then proceed. Right?